# LED Fails to illuminate, what am I not seeing in my configuration(s)?

Tags: led, resistors, basic, low-voltage, protoboard

I'm working on a super simple circuit, I want to light the LED.

Power Source 1: 5.5v from 9v battery through breadboard power supply module
Power Source 2: 5.5v from lab bench PSU
LED Info: Vf - 3v to 3.2v; If = 20mA;
Resistor: 150 +/- 2% - brown/green/black/black/brown (the close-up picture makes the browns look purple, but they **are** brown)

Things to note:

1. I have used a multimeter to test the connectivity, it beeps
2. I have used a multimeter to verify voltage is getting through, it does
3. I have used several different breadboards AND multiple tie points for each breadboard.
4. I have used multiple different colors (adjusting the resistor for each based on Vf & If for the color)
5. Whenever I check the LED connectivity with the 3.3v with an LED that can hold up to it, it lights up, again in multiple tie points
6. weirdly, if I use a jumper cable to connect row abcde to fghij, the LED does not light up (again checking multiple tie points, and multiple boards), but when I directly connect the anode to abcde and the cathode to fghij it does light up.
7. Yes I make sure that the anode and cathode or appropriately placed
8. Yes I use the multimeter to check everything every new setup
9. Yes I have used multiple values of Resistors pushing the resistance as low as is safely possible for the LED
10. Yes I have checked the Ohms of for each resistor that I have used
11. Yes, I have used both sides of the power tie strips

**Working Configurations:**
3.3v from lab bench PSU
[image: 3.3v from lab bench PSU]

3.3v from 9v via power supply module
[image: 3.3v from 9v via power supply module]

**Non-Working Configurations:**
5.5v from lab bench PSU
[image: 5.5v from lab bench PSU]

5.5v from 9v battery via power supply module
[image: 5.5v from 9v battery via power supply module]

close up of parts
[image: close up of parts]

Comment: The LED is shorted because the five nests of each islet are interconnected.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Classic beginner's breadboard mistake.

[image]

*Figure 1. We somehow expect the green connections to be zero ohms while the red one is an open-circuit!*

All five sockets in a row are the one terminal strip. The LED is short-circuited.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: You are aware that the five sockets in each row are connected? You've plugged both pins of the LED into the same row. They're now connected to each other so there is no voltage across the LED and no current will flow through it.

Comment: Yeah just figured that out. :facepalm:

Comment: The human mind is a strange thing!

Comment: I greatly appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Wow. I've been using breadboards for 30 years and my initial reaction to the image was "Yeah, that looks about right, the LED should light up". The brain just filters out certain things. Good thing we will soon be replaced with AI.

Comment: That resistor is pulling 1/5 watt with 5.5V, should be getting a little warm.

Answer (score 10):

My students often made this mistake. So I forced myself to make this image of a similar board with drawn connecting lines.

[image: Board (in front)]

Also, I removed (with great difficulty) the adhesive pad from the underside of the circuit board to reveal the connecting spring elements.

[image: Board behind]

Finally, I even removed the spring elements so they could see their device. This "demo board" was constantly sitting on the workbenches.

[image: A workbench]

And yet they were still making this wrong connection. As a result, LEDs, multimeters configured as ammeters...

[image: Blown multimeter fuses]

... and pots suffered the most.

[image: Blown pot]

I recommend you sacrifice a board and "reverse engineering" it:-)

Comment: And if you don't want to sacrifice a board like this, don't worry, one of them will sacrifice itself eventually.